# Как сгенерировать все возможные графы из 3, 5 и т. д. вершин?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Пусть даны 4 точки (A,B,C,D) Как сгенерировать все возможные связи ? Я могу сгенерировать на python все возможные ребра, но вот как сгенерировать именно графы?

Т. е., например А->B->C->D, A->B->A->C->D и т. д. - как найти все возможные маршруты для всех комбинаций пар вершин?

Comment: Ориентированная дуга - это упорядоченная пара вершин. Вы можете перебрать все возможные пары вершин, засунуть их в список пар, после чего сделать полный перебор комбинаций за 2^(n*(n-1)).

Comment: @EzikBro вот мне интересен сам алгоритм? Вот есть у меня [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('A', 'F'), ('A', 'G'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('B', 'F'), ('B', 'G'), ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'F'), ('C', 'G'), ('D', 'E'), ('D', 'F'), ('D', 'G'), ('E', 'F'), ('E', 'G'), ('F', 'G')]

Comment: Ни в одном из постов не упомянули, ориентированный ли граф.  A->B->A есть цикл,а количество путей с циклами бесконечно. Отнеситесь к постановке задачи ответственно - само по себе построение точной формулировки может Вас привести к решению.

Comment: @MBo Так это и не цикл, я указал тупиковые путь, где чтобы добраться до след вершин, нужно сделать шаг назад

Comment: @Mbo нет никаких в графе циклов, нет направлений. Просто перебрать все возможные связи. Есть 3 точки, найти все способы соединения их между собой, вот такая задача у меня, только точек 6. Без циклов, без петель

Comment: Для практических целей  - сделать список нужных графов и далее его использовать - может пригодиться [Nauty](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) с ключом -с

Answer (score 0):

Для размера n<=6 подойдёт простой метод с отсевом несвязных графов:

Проходим все числа в диапазоне n-1..2<sup>n*(n-1)/2</sup>-1, каждое представляем в бинарной записи. Нулевой бит в k-й позиции означает отсутствие k-го ребра, 1  - наличие.

Число в показателе степени - это количество возможных рёбер, а начинаем с n-1 - поскольку это минимальное число рёбер для образования связного графа.

Проверяем граф на связность.

Для n=6 это всего 32 тыс. графов. Далее уже будет сложнее...